# Mysqli Prepared Statement Fetch Assoc

Tags: php, mysqli

I am making a mysqli class for my website, but I'm stuck.

This is my class:

```
class Database  {

    private $mysqli = '';
    private $params = '';
    private $result = '';

    function Database($hostname, $username, $password, $database) {
        $this->mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database);

        if ($this->mysqli->connect_errno) {
            printf('Error #%s -> %s', $this->mysqli->connect_errno, $this->mysqli->connect_error);
            exit;
        }
    }

    public function setQuery($query) {
        $this->result = $this->mysqli->prepare($query); 
        $this->params = array();
        return $this;
    }

    public function setParam($type, $value) {
        $this->params[$type] = $value;

        return $this;
    }

    public function execute() {
        $params = $this->params;

        foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
            $this->result->bind_param($key, $value);
        }

        $user = $this->result->result_metadata()->fetch_assoc();
        echo $user['username'];
    }


}
```

I'm using:

```
Core::$database->setQuery('SELECT * FROM habbo_characters WHERE id = ?')->setParam('i', 1)->execute();
```

But I got no output / empty string as output. What i'm doing wrong?
The setParam function works correctly, it's not that.
And it contains user with id 1 (the sql).

Comment: Do not use mysqli. Use PDO. it already have everything you need from this class

Comment: There are a lot of things wrong there. You need to reread the documentation.

Comment: Debug your code to locate exactly where the problem is.

Answer (score -1):

use PDO:

```
<?php
/* Execute a prepared statement by passing an array of values */
$sql = 'SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour';
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
$sth->execute(array(':calories' => 150, ':colour' => 'red'));
$red = $sth->fetchAll();
$sth->execute(array(':calories' => 175, ':colour' => 'yellow'));
$yellow = $sth->fetchAll();
?>
```

more examples can be found here: http://php.net/manual/de/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: dont see why -1, PDO is ligit alternative, though in the question it clearly states `MySQLi`